# Delphi 10.4 and TVirtualStringTree Hint formatting

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview

Since updating to Delphi 10.4 I am finding that the hints appearing in TVirtualStringTree are not  properly scaled on my Hi-Res monitor appear at least twice the height they should be. The problem does not extend to the rest of the application as I am using TMS THTMLHint but TVirtualStringTree doesn't recognise this control and uses the standard windows Hint.

I suspect it is due to a change made in 10.4 to address this [Size of hints in Delphi 10.3 Rio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63189602/size-of-hints-in-delphi-10-3-rio) issue.

Has anyone else had this issue with 10.4?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Embarcadero fixed a long broken dpi scaling of the Hint window in RAD Studio 10.4:

https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-24541

I guess this change is responsible for the wrong hint font size of Virtual Treeview in Delphi 10.4. Please open an issue in the [issue tracker](https://github.com/JAM-Software/Virtual-TreeView/issues) respecting the guidelines for submitting bugs.

Comment: It seems to work as expected on a new form in 10.4 so I will have to investigate further before submitting an issue.